# Session Timeout Development

Tags: user-research, frontend-development

I don't want to re-invent the wheel but what would you think (ballpark) would be the estimated development time (hours) to add a notification to the user?

Approach - After x amount of minutes a popup, with a countdown, will give an option to stay logged in or log out. If no action is taken the user will be logged out and a different pop up would explain the reasoning, something like "you were logged out because of being inactive"

I was quoted 70 hours, roughly converts to $5000, for those 2 pop ups and think I am getting caught with my pants down...

Is there an easier approach to get the hours down?

Comment: Since this question is more about implementation rather than User Experience design, I'd recommend asking this on the [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) sister site.

Comment: Can someone vote to close this question? I do not have enough reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

A number of things effect development time. Without knowing all the details 70 hours may or may not be reasonable for your specific situation.

As Max mentioned, this is not the correct site for this type of question, and since you are really asking for project estimation and not how to address specific programming problems, Stackoverflow is probably not a good place to ask either.

I suggest you get a second or third opinion / bid from other outsourcing companies or consultants if you think 70 hours is too much.

Comment: Np, I hope you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how the current site is built. If there is a common include for every page where you can add this new code... I'd argue that 2 days effort would be more than enough. (~16hours)

On a really rough legacy site with little consistency this would balloon up to a full week (80hours)